# How can I rename the response from an http request?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a relatively simple Java/Tomcat requirement but I can't figure out how to implement it.

I have an HTTPS POST request into a specific server URL, call it `/myserver/somecontroller.do`.

The controller method correctly returns an Excel document with a mime type of `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

This all works fine.   The problem is that the response gets downloaded on the client computer with the name `somecontroller.do` instead of something that Excel understands, like `myspreadsheet.xls`.

So when the user clicks the file to open it, they get an ugly error message instead of the spreadsheet they were expecting, and I get a trouble ticket in my inbox.

They could rename the file, but the optimal solution is to have the system name the file correctly.

How can I modify the HTTPServletResponse parameters so that it understands it's sending a document called `myspreadsheet.xls` instead of `somecontroller.do`?

Some cleaned-up example code:

```
// Returns a spreadsheet, but it's called "somethingelse.do" instead of 
// "somethingelse.xls"


@RequestMapping(value="/something/somthingelse.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doSomething(@ModelAttribute ReportModel reportModel, BindingResult bindResult,HttpServletResponse response,Model model) throws Exception{
    Workbook reportObj = ReportService.generateExcel(ReportService.getReportData(reportModel.getReportParameters()));
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = (HSSFWorkbook) reportObj;
    workbook.write(out);
    out.flush();
    return SomeViewMapping.VIEW_SOMETHING.getViewName();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more header.  Something like:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myspreadsheet.xls");
```

Comment: Thank you.   It's always nice to get some help from StackOverflow.